# Primeng Dialog Modal (p-dialog) freeze the parent page after close

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I have a simple PrimeNG Dialog Modal (p-dialog) in Angular and when close the modal, it keeps the parent page frozen/grey out/disabled. I am not using any CSS. Below is my script. I also had to add enableProdMode(); to be able to make Modal visible and displayed for all environments.

Is there anything i am missing?

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="projectUploadDialog" [style]="{ width: '600px' }" header="Project Upload" [modal]="true" styleClass="p-fluid">
<div class="card">
    Something here
</div>
</p-dialog>
```

Here is the dependencies and versions:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
"primeflex": "^3.3.1",
"primeicons": "^6.0.1",
"primeng": "^16.2.0",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.13.0"
},
```